# PCB layout/schematics of solenoid lock control - Problem - uncontrollable unlocking

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, control, solenoid

I have a problem with opening solenoid locks. Sometimes, immediately upon connecting the power, and other times after about half an hour or even an hour, the locks start to open uncontrollably.
I have measured things, and also theoretically, it should work.

I am attaching specifications for the solenoid locks that are used, the circuit diagram, and the layout.

Do anyone suggest some improvements? Or can spot a problem through attached pictures.
BG, Blaz

[image: Lock specifications]

[image: Schematics1]

[image: Schematics2]

[image: PCB]

[image: Layout components]
[image: Polygon]

Edit:

I forgot to mention, thanks to Chester Gillon.
We took from PCB also MCU, so we eliminated issue where the MCU pins would drive locks.

Comment: W.r.t. ``the locks start to open uncontrollably``, from the information it isn't clear if either (a) something goes wrong in the MCU software which causes the software to unexpectedly change the MCU output pins which control the solenoid locks (b) the MCU output pins remain in the expected state but the solenoid locks still open. Can you [edit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/699141/edit) the question to describe what debugging steps have been taken so far.

Comment: I did, thank you.

Comment: Does anything get damaged that needs replacing? Is the 24 volts definitely stable? Please link the data sheet of the MOSFET.

Comment: 24V is definitely stable.
Following mosfet is now damaged on one output. 
right now is alternative mosfet (used on current PCB):
https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/BUK98150-55A.pdf

Comment: Are your locks rated for continuous use?

Comment: So the solenoids should be off, until MCU turns it on? When these uncontrollable triggerings happen, have you measured any points in the schematics with a multimeter or an oscilloscope what could be the problem and where? Your gate resistors are very suspicious thogh.

Comment: As the other comment, why do you have the series gate resistor so high?  The 100k combined with the 47k reduces the gate voltage to 3.8 V or less.  Some of the MOSFET parameters are listed using a 10 V gate voltage.

Comment: Definitely was a mistake 100k resistor. After replacing with 100R, issue stays the same. 

Locks should unlock with signal from MCU. So no impact if microcontroller is present or not.